# http.post запрос к php возвращает false

Tags: php, angularjs

После покупки SSL сертификата, возникла проблема в получанием данных погоды с openweather.org. Решил перенести получение данных в php скрипт.

На клиенте запрос (его чать) оформлен следующим образом:

```
 $http.post(weather, angular.toJson({"lalitude": $scope.lat, "longitude": $scope.lon})).then(function (data) {
            $scope.weather = data.data;
            console.log ('Weather request success', $scope.weather);
```

В php скрипте я его получаю так:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($postdata, true);

$lat = $request['lat'];
$lon = $request['lon'];
```

Далее идет запрос, обработка его и отправка обратно на клиент:

```
$urlAPI = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" .$lat. "&lon=" .$lon. "&units=metric&appid=b0ef240f1eb180e6ccdcb22";

$weather_request = file_get_contents($urlAPI);

$weather = json_decode($weather_request, true);

echo json_encode($weather);
```

И на выходе в клиента я получаю false.

Если же присвоить изначально переменным $lat и $lon числовые значения, то все работает хорошо.

В чем может быть причина? В том, что переменные не принимают числовые значения, а строковые?

```
$lat = $request['lat'];
$lon = $request['lon'];
```

Comment: Отладьте и посмотрите что в $postdata, вы же отправляете JSON данные, а не обычный POST через multipart-form

Comment: Еще, мне кажется, вы отправляете параметры lalitude и longitude, а в php ожидаете lat и lon.